# 2 dice rolling histogram python parameter passing issue

Tags: python

```
import random
roll_list = []  
num_rolls = 100 

def init_list():
    for x in range (0,13):
      roll_list.append(0)

def roll_dice():
    dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
    dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
    roll = dice1 + dice2

def update_list(roll):
    previousvalue = roll_list.pop(roll)
    roll_list.insert(roll,previousvalue + 1)

def print_histogram():
  for numbers in range(0,13):
    print(numbers + ":", "*" * roll_list.pop(numbers))

init_list()
for y in range(0,num_rolls):
  update_list(roll_dice())
print(roll_list)
print_histogram(roll_list)
```

```
# sample output:

 0: 
 1: 
 2: ***
 3: ******
 4: ***************
 5: ************
 6: ************
 7: ************
 8: ***********
 9: ***********
10: ***********
11: ****
12: ***
```

OUTPUT I am not sure how to pass the parameter so i can print the histogram i tried inserting roll_list into it but it doesn't seem to work.
This is the error message  i get.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 64, in 
TypeError: print_histogram() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Everything works except the histogram if you could comment on how i can get it working that would be great.

UPDATE : WORKING CODE:

```
import random

roll_list = []  
num_rolls = 100 

def init_list():
    for x in range (0,13):
      roll_list.append(0)

def roll_dice():
    dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
    dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
    roll = dice1 + dice2
    return roll  

def update_list(roll):
    previousvalue = roll_list.pop(roll)
    roll_list.insert(roll,previousvalue + 1)


def print_histogram():
  for numbers in range(0,13):
    print(numbers, ":", "*" * roll_list[numbers])

# main program
init_list()
for y in range(0,num_rolls):
  update_list(roll_dice())

print(roll_list)
print_histogram()
```

Comment: Did you already consult the documentation about function parameters? https://docs.python.org/3.8/glossary.html#term-parameter

Comment: @LydiavanDyke Yes, i did look at that aswell as other power points on this specific problem.

Comment: @LydiavanDyke Now it works but only for the first 6 numbers instead of 12

Comment: @LydiavanDyke Nvm. just fixed my issue. It wasnt parameters but it was the the function on line 34

Answer (score 1):

FINAL CODE:

```
import random

roll_list = []  
num_rolls = 100 

def init_list():
    for x in range (0,13):
      roll_list.append(0)

def roll_dice():
    dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
    dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
    roll = dice1 + dice2
    return roll  

def update_list(roll):
    previousvalue = roll_list.pop(roll)
    roll_list.insert(roll,previousvalue + 1)


def print_histogram():
  for numbers in range(0,13):
    print(numbers, ":", "*" * roll_list[numbers])

# main program
init_list()
for y in range(0,num_rolls):
  update_list(roll_dice())

print(roll_list)
print_histogram()
```